# Is it possible to save Javascript's console.log as a file in JSP (Tomcat)?

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat

A web page made of JSP was run by Tomcat.

What I'm curious about is...

Can Javscript output log files (tomcat/logs/*.log) in real time?

"console.log" as a file or... is there any other way?

Comment: javascript is run on the browser. Which is on the computer a thousand miles away. Those tomcat log files are on the server. If you want the javascript (on the client) to end up writing log files (on the server), you'd have to write a boatload of code to send it. Note that hackers will IMMEDIATELY fill your disk up with 4GB of spam and worse if you do this.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I understood,
JavaScript can overload the server,
But there is no problem because I am a server that only uses it internally,
I wonder if it's possible,
If it's impossible...
I'll have to write it in java through ajax..

Comment: @rzwitserloot I dont see why sending log messages via some REST call would be different (from a security standpoint) than any other REST communication between client and server (which, of course, must be properly secured).

Comment: the insinuation is that the client's logs just go to the log file on disk verbatim, @GyroGearless - which you can't do here, so the question is far more complicated. Can unauthenticated users send _any_ logs? Is there a flood limit on authenticated ones? Complicated questions, thus leading to: No, you can't 'just' log the console to a server-local file, no.

Answer (score 0):

From a technical standpoint you can of course wrap console.log to send a request to the server and write that request to a file on the server. The method for doing this has to be implemented by you though, since by default it doesn't exist.

From a security point of view this is not really a good idea, see @rzwitzerloot's comment about the ease of abusing that system.